# Cannot compile c code on netbeans windows

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I am not able to complile c code in netbeans I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot run program "C:\cygwin64\bin\makeinfo" (in directory "C:\Users\prjwl\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Hearts"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

I have followed netbeans intallation guidelines and cygwin seems to be working from the command line.

I have also checked for missing dll's and checked settings in Tools->options->c++ to see if the build tools are set properly
[image: Snapshot of the configuration]

If anyone knows what exactly am I doing wrong, Help me

Comment: Sounds like a directory permissions issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makeinfo` is not part of your C compilation process, it is a documentation generator, used usually in conjunction with GNU autools.

You should be able to install it by installing the `texinfo` Cygwin package.

Note that `makeinfo` is NOT `make`, by far. If you need `make`, install that Cygwin package as well, and set "Make Command" to `C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe` (in your case).